# Complex Data binding using ViewModels in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, knockout-mapping-plugin

Update for my question i have an fiddle here         `http://jsfiddle.net/googlegovind/4hLw86of/`

```
var initialData = [{ "firstQuest": "",
    "Options": [
      {
        "option": " ",
        "coption": " "
      }]
    }];
var QuizModel = function(Questions) {
    var self = this;
    self.Questions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(Questions, function(question) {
        return { firstQuest: question.firstQuest,
         // lastName: contact.lastName,
         Options: ko.observableArray(question.option) };
    }));

    self.addQuest = function() {
        self.Questions.push({
            firstQuest: "",
            Qtype:"",

            Options: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };

    self.removeQuest = function(question) {
        self.Questions.remove(question);
    };

    self.addOption = function(question) {
        question.Options.push({
            option: " ",
            coption: " "
            // number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeOption = function(option) {
        $.each(self.Questions(), function() { this.Options.remove(option) })
    };

    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.Questions), null, 2));


    };


    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");


};

ko.applyBindings(new QuizModel(initialData));
```

i want to create an quizmodel which have different questions and options .The fiddle is working but i need each questions in different views which comes when clicking next button and if previous is clicked i need to go back and edit each questions.i tried a lot but its not working..
atlast i want to save this data into an array(the data in lastSavedJson)

Comment: if you can add a fiddle with your html that would be helpful to get you a working one .

Comment: updated the question with fiddle @supercool